# ResultSet getString character encoding for unicode characters

Tags: java, oracle, swing, character-encoding

In my swing application I am going to display hindi unicode charecters from the database.
When I am displaying name, it showing as it is, not as a hindi string.

But when I hardcoded it into the program it is showing correctly. What is the problem. Is there any charecter encoding option while getting the data from database. I am using oracle xe with Netbeans.

```
    String name = rs.getString("name");
    jLabel1.setText(name);
```

Here it displaying unicode charecters as it is.
But here

```
    String name = "\u0938\u093e\u092e\u093e\u0928\u094d\u092f";
    jLabel1.setText(name);
```

It showing correctly. Where is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The issue lies in the encoding that Oracle is using.  You have to set it up to use UTF-8 in the database as well.  Unfortunately, you can't fix this in the JDBC classes.